# jQuery Sibling/Child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to select all the inputs with a specific name attribute inside a row containing a column containing a particular image.

The code below is an illustrative example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="A">
      <img src="X">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="b">
      <input type="" name="b">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="A">
      <img src="Y">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="b">
      <input type="" name="b">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So based on the example above, I would like to know which jQuery selector I can use to select the `inputs` of `name` "a" that are inside a `td` tag that is inside a `tr` tag containing and `img` tag with `src` = "X";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use `:has()` to find the `tr` with the required image and then find the child inputs by name, something like this:

```js
$('tr:has(img[src="X"]) input[name="a"]').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="A">
      <img src="X">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="b">
      <input type="" name="b">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="A">
      <img src="Y">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="b">
      <input type="" name="b">
    </td>
    <td class="A">
      <input type="" name="a">
      <input type="" name="a">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And this will work even if the ``input`` tags are inside ``td`` tags?

Comment: It'll work so long as the `input` are a descendant of the `tr` at any level.